# PHP detect phone type and echo

Tags: php, user-agent

I'm trying to identify a visitor's phone type based on their UserAgent string. I can't find the error in my code, however.

```
<?php

//create an array to be filled with phone type
$arr = phones();

$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
$palmpre = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"webOS");
$berry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BlackBerry");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$nokia = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Nokia");

if ($iphone || $android || $palmpre || $ipod || $berry || $nokia == true)
{
    echo "Specially for you as $iphone owner!";
}

?>
```

Comment: And what do you want ? Please give us some more information.

Comment: There are great libraries to do that for you in much more detail, UA recognition is really nothing you should reinvent!

Answer (score 4):

Taking into account the other comments, you shouldn't do this yourself.  These user agents are nowhere near an exhaustive list. But if you'd like to experiment yourself I'd recommend trying out something like the following.

Also if `"iPhone"` is not found then the condition is automatically false and no other statements will be evaluated.

I like doing something like:

```
$has_mobile_ua = FALSE;
$user_agents = array('iPhone', 'Android', 'webOS', 'BlackBerry', 'iPod', 'Nokia');

foreach ($user_agents as $user_agent) {
  if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $user_agent) !== FALSE) {
    $has_mobile_ua = TRUE;
    break;
  }
}

if ($has_mobile_ua) {
  // your code
}
```

Comment: How about `if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $user_agent) !== false)` ... Don't forget how `strpos` works ...

Comment: This works rather well. You can add an `else` statement with an `echo` if not in the list.

Comment: @dm03514 it returns `0` because you have no `else` statement, and you're viewing in with a browser not set in the `array`. You have to `tell it` what to do, if otherwise.

Comment: Just to cearlify the usage; its just to use in a text;

Default (user agent is not in the list)
Hello smartphone user!

If any of the ones is in the list:
Hello iPhone user, Welcome!

So its only echo of the pre-defined phone types within a line of text that i need.

Answer (score 0):

for this case, try change strpos with stristr..

```
$iphone = stristr("$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]","iphone");
```

it's work for me, with same code like yours..